# How to convert custom object key of a hash map into JSON in java

Tags: java, json

I've got a hash map like -

```
Map<Employee,Duty>
```

where **Employee** and **Duty** objects are like below -

```
class Employee
{
 e_id; // will be used in equals() and hashcode()
 e_DOB;
 e_name; 
}

class Duty
{
 d_type;
 d_timing;
}
```

Is there a way to convert this map into JSON so that JSON will be generated for all the fields of **Employee** and **Duty** objects ?

I'm not sure if this can be done in the same as for any hash map having a primitive class as key. i.e. `Map<String,Employee>`

Comment: How would the `Employee` key be converted to JSON? Post an example of the JSON you expect.

Comment: Something random you just came up with.

Comment: JSON pairs are composed of a JSON string and a JSON value. Read about the JSON format, [here](http://json.org/). You can still define a conversion function from `Employee` to a JSON string, but you haven't done that. We have no idea what you are trying to do.

Comment: It's the toString() output eclipse generates :P

Answer (score -1):

Use eg [JSON In Java](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json)

```
class Employee 
{
public JSONObject toJSON(){
JSONObject resultJson = new JSONObject();
resultJson.put("e_id", e_id);
resultJson.put("e_DOB",e_DOB);
resultJson.put("e_name",e_name);
return resultJson 
}
}
```

Comment: But this will not address need to convert fields of Employee into JSON

Comment: I rewrote it for Employee .

Answer (score -2):

I believe Gson is the perfect solution for you.
Have a look at an example:
http://kodejava.org/how-do-i-convert-map-into-json/